# How to display model attribute in AngularJS using Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to switch from a pure JavaScript implementation to using AngularJS. I am unable to figure how to use the model attribute with the form that is now using AngularJS.

> **Controller**

```
@ModelAttribute("frequencies")
public Frequency[] frequencies() {
    return Frequency.values();
}

@ModelAttribute("genders")
public Gender[] personGender() {
    return Gender.values();
}

@RequestMapping(value="uform", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadUFormPage(Model m) {
    return "userManagment";
}
```

The initial JSP displayed all the `Enum`s as:

```
  <form:select path="gender" id="genderOptions">
    <form:option value="">Select Gender</form:option>
    <c:forEach items="${genders}" var="gender">
      <form:option value="${gender}">${gender}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>>
  </form:select>
```

I am looking for an AngularJS equivalent of this JSP code since in AngularJS all data is passed as JSON.

Comment: shouldn't it be **Java** rather than **Javascript** ? It's confusing, spring and javascript

Comment: There is a front end page that is in javascript that the end user can see. Does that answer your question?

Comment: you have just given Java code, I think you should provide the javascript code, and HTML as well

Comment: updated the question